# How to do a files selector in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, file, selector

I want to do a files selector like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxYQT.png for my programm but I don't know how to do this...

Can you please help me ? I'm using Xcode 5 on Mac OS X 10.8.5

Answer (score 0):

That is called an NSOpenPanel. Here's the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html